# How do I disable any widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my app, I need to disable many widgets many times. But I cannot find convenient way to do so? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: disable meaning: "do not pass any pointer events down the tree" ? if so, check `IgnorePointer` / `AbsorbPointer`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can wrap any widget in `flutter` with the `AbsorbPointer` widget so that you can enable or disable the widget:

```
body: AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: true,
  child: ...
)
```

The value `true` on `absorbing` will disable any tap on the child.

Comment: This widget is not disabling Rawkeyboard events, is there any widget or way we can use to achieve that? @Ashok

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about TextField widget you can set readOnly atribute to true.
If its a checkBox or DropdownButton pass null for onChanged attribute.

Answer (score -2):

if you use `inkwell`, so pass `null` to `onTap`.